# Application does not start properly when called on Windows startup

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, windows-10

I have a strange problem. I have an Qt application with dynamic linked DLLs.

When I open the .exe file the application starts correctly, even if I open it from a desktop shortcut as soon, as I see the desktop on Windows start.

But when I add it to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` it does not start correctly.

e.g. (edit) the log file is not created and the QlistView doesnt display any information (list of items) from the SQLite database, and I cannot connect to a server via QTcpSocket. (even if the autostart version starts after the manually started).

(edit) the log file doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Perhaps it started before the desktop environment was available.

Comment: Are you using an absolute or a relative path to access the database?

Comment: so, should I delay the initialisation of the app? 
Is there a way to check if the environment is ready?

Comment: I am using a relative path. My log shows, that the database was opened correctly.

Comment: Do you see errors when you query the database? You can put debug output to see, why your list of items is empty.

Comment: correction. I've deleted the log file, and a new file was not created.
I'll try to write qDebug to a QTextEdit and see what it shows.

Comment: At this time, the current directory points to c:\windows\system32 directory. So relative paths are relative to this directory. You should use absolute directories here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The solution was to change the current directory to the app directory by:

```
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

At startup the current directory is set to windows/system32.